# Why in $S^2$ is there no spin structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, quantum-mechanics, spin-geometry

For a Dirac fermion (spin half) on $S^2$, we have both the general covariant derivatives and the relativistic Hamitonian. What does the claim "in $S^2$ there is no spin structure" means? A reference for physicist is wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Are your first and second sentences related (aside from both mentioning $S^2$)?

Comment: In fact, we do not know whether these two sentences are related or not. We do not know the difference between a spin particle on $S^2$ and a spin structure in it. Please help me to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to sound condescending, but have you read the Wikipedia article about [spin structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure)? If so, can you be more specific about what you are unsure about?

Comment: A better way to ask the question would be to give a precise reference (preferably with a link) of where you found the statement "in $S^2$ there is no spin structure". The way spin structure is defined in mathematics, $S^2$ does have a spin structure.

Comment: Sorry for I am not comfortable with pure mathematical literature.  For physics side we have,  A.A. Abrikosov, Fermion states on the sphere $ S^2 $. Int. J. Mod. Phys. A 17, 885–889 (2002). For mathematics side, spinor can not be defined on the sphere. Possibly, "in S2 there is no spin structure" does not mean "spinor can not be defined on it". Am I right?

Comment: At present it is unclear what your question is about.  As Igor mentions, $S^2$ does have a spin structure.  The definition of spin structure for a 2-manifold is a little bit nuanced, my guess is the reference you cite perhaps forgets the nuance in the case of 2-dimensional manifolds.

Comment: Hi Quanhui, Welcome to Mathoverflow! I think this question is a perfect one for https://math.stackexchange.com/, which has a much broader scope than MO has.

Comment: @QuanhuiLiu Where in Abrikosov's paper is the statement that there are no spinors on the 2-sphere?  In fact, the first line in the abstract of the paper is "We solve for the spectrum and eigenfunctions of Dirac operator on the sphere."

Comment: My closest guess is "there are no harmonic spinors on $S^2$" (kernel of Dirac operator is trivial).